# android IncomingHandler not fired when we close the application by removing from recent list

Tags: android, ibeacon

I am writing a sample application for detecting iBeacons through android app. I am using the code from the following site https://github.com/AlvinBert/android-ibeacon-Jaalee-source-code
  With the code from the above site i can able to detect ibeacons and send notifications. When i check the running apps, there is 1 Service running.

If i close my application, by long press the home key and remove my app from the Recent list, then i didn't get the notifications, but still 1 service is running.

I debug the code and found that "IncomingHandler" is not getting fired which is in the service inside the "com.communicate.ibeacon.service.IBeaconService" package.

I need this to be called continuously, even after the application closes. Since, i am new to android could you please point me what to do, to achieve this.

Thanks
Jai

Answer (score 0):

The beacon library you mention is an unauthorized copy of the Pro Android iBeacon Library formerly provided by Radius Networks.  As the original author of that library, I can confirm that it would not detect beacons after the app being killed until a power cycle of the phone takes place.  Unfortunately, this library had been discontinued by my company over licensing issues.

Library issues aside, one approach you could take to accomplish your goal is to use Androud Broadcast Intents to automatically re-launch your app based on system events like power connected and disconnected.  This will not relaunch immediately, but will typically do so once a day when a device is in normal use.

Comment: Yes, i saw Android iBeacon Library provided by Radius Networks. Both the codes more or less resembles the same. If it is the case, then is there any library that can detect beacons even after closing the app.

Comment: Can we override any methods in that library to reinvoke the scanning.